# Can a double-factorial be a perfect square?

Tags: number-theory, factorial

The title says it, basically. My question is $-$ for $ n \ge 2 $, can  $n!!$ be a perfect square, where $!!$ represents the [double-factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial)? My conjecture is no, but I can't seem to be able to find a good proof for this.

Comment: Can a factorial be a perfect square?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No, for odd $n,$ there is a prime between $(n-1)/2$ and $n.$ The exponent of this prime in factoring $n!!$ is one, that is, odd.

*Edit.* looking at even numbers and the definition, it appears
$$  (2n)!! = 2^n n!  $$
in which case we ignore the exponent of $2$ and concentrate on $n!,$ which cannot be a square either for this $n \geq 3,$ also because of an odd prime. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial#Relation_to_the_factorial).

Comment: Just want to note that he used [Bertrand's postulate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand's_postulate). Very nice argument.

Comment: Beautiful; thank you very much!

Comment: I don't understand your dividing-out strategy. Are you claiming that if $n$ is even, then $n!!=2^mk!!$ for some integer $m$ and odd $k$?

Comment: @TonyK, never used $n!!$ for even $n$ before. The definition seems to say $(2n)!! = 2^n n!$ Then the same argument applies to $n!$